# How to define this partial-order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

One element x in a partial-order amount is maximal if it dosen't exists $x \neq y$  with $x \le y$ and we have something that is called minimal if there doesn't exist  $ y \neq x$ with $y \le x$.

And we have $ S = \mathbb{N} $ that we let to be the Natural Numbers.
And i wonder how i can define a Partial-order on $\vec{S} \times \vec{S}$
there it exists a unique maximal element but no minimal element.
And to draw the Hassel-Diagram that contains all $(a,b)$ with   $a+b\le 4.$

I know that a Partial-Order should be Reflexive and Symmetric and Transistive but this is very abstract to think in natural numbers i think i must be very general to test this?

I am stuck?

Comment: Comments (i) I think your definitions of maximal is wrong, there should be NO $y$ bigger than $x$; (ii) I think you need to clarify your problem, is the "$\le$" in the 5th line the usual order on $\mathbb{N}$ or the partial order $\le$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks i have changed it but what do you mean by the 5th line and i try to clarify it?

Comment: You count the lines down, 1,2,3,4,5. It ends with $a+b\le 4$. Is that $\le$ the usual order on $\mathbb{N}$ or is it the order relation you are defining? And what does the little arrow on top of $S$ signify?